# How to implement share Picture using Twitter App in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter

I've successfully tried SLComposeViewController and TWTRComposer(Twitter-Kit/Fabric) , but they both require native/built-in twitter login i.e. login through iPhone setting.

I'm working on an application which requires if user is not logged in within native/built-in login, he can share picture via installed twitter application.

Is there any way to share picture via twitter application installed in phone, like we do in case of Facebook using Facebook SDK?